# ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Users):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have added a `t.boolean :admin` field to my Devise migration file. It was saying that it was an unpermitted parameter in the console so I attempted to create a protected permitter for the `:admin` value when the form is submitted.

Here is my `Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController`:

```
    class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
      before_action :configure_permitted_parameters

      protected

      #Permitting the admin boolean
      def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up).push(:admin)
      end
    end
```

And my `routes.rb` file with the `devise_for` method.

```
    devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "users/registrations" }
```

I cannot seem to fix `ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant Users):` despite me looking on stack overflow for 30 minutes and trying to rename a couple of things. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controller has probably the wrong name or it is placed in the wrong folder. When following Ruby on Rails conventions then a controller named `Users::RegistrationsController` should be defined in a file named `app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb`.

Comment: Had to add a users folder to my controllers folder, thanks!